# Why i cannot use gmail smtp in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, smtp, gmail

This is my setting:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'prahbari82@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'My gmail password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and i use CBV's:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class UserLogin(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'


class UserPassReset(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')
    email_template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_email.html'


class PasswordResetDone(auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'accounts/reset_done.html'


class PasswordResetConfirm(auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')


class PasswordResetComplete(auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_complete.html'
```

**But I don't get any errors
I also turned on the less secure app!**
I also used 2 verification but it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

*TLS = True* only if you are using port 465.

Comment: less secure app is on  and EMAIL_PORT is 465 but nothing happens

Comment: If you want more informations, please add more code. Where is the part of sending email? Have you already read in django site how to send email? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this challenge. I searched everywhere online but no answer. Finally, I got a hint which led me to try what worked for me.

1st: in your *`settings.py`* if you set `EMAIL_USE_TLS = False`,

then set `EMAIL_USE_SSL = True` and `EMAIL_PORT = 465` .

Otherwise, if you set  `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`,

then set `EMAIL_USE_SSL = False` and  `EMAIL_PORT = 587` .

2nd: in Your terminal run; `npm run build`, instead of `npm start` .

NOTE: Always run `npm run build` whenever you make any changes in your front-end. Although, there is another way to make it automatic but that is not within the scope of this issue.